# Using L7 to classify pcap data

Tags: untagged

I've recently become familiar with the [Layer 7 Filter project](http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/), and it's ability to classify protocols is quite interesting.

All of the information about its use, however, concerns using the filters to do queueing in real-time in order to implement bandwidth management/QOS. What I'm interested in is using the filters to classify traffic that I've already captured in pcap format.

Comments, hints, experiences, references, or wtfs, welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tcpreplay
wireplay
preplay

There are a bunch of packages that do tcp replay of pcap files.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept, this is a great idea, though I'll have to do this from a machine off-network to prevent network from having to deal with the now-irrelevant traffic.